# How to convert an Object with Map to JSON Object

Tags: typescript

I am trying to convert an object containing map to json using JSON.stringify().
But after the conversion map data gets cleared.
How do i solve this issue?

frieghtChargesJSon:string; //declared variable
 frieghtChargesJSon=JSON.stringify(frieghtChargeInfo)

I want to convert object itself to JSon ,not just the map

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string = JSON.stringify(Array.from(map.entries()));
```

Comment: I want entire Object to be converted into JSON not just the map

Comment: @shyni const mapObj = m => {
  return Array.from(m).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
    obj[key] = value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
};
JSON.stringify(mapObj(map));

Comment: Actually this doesn't work for me .It doesn't convert entire Object to JSON

Comment: Thanks for your help